# How to write the dimensions and position of each form?

Tags: imagemagick

I have the input image beloe for which I´d like to get the size and coordinates and write inside or at the top of each rectangle.

For now I was able to get the black rectangles data with this script

```
$ convert input.png -fill black +opaque '#FFFFFF' \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=5000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 output.png | awk '/srgb\(0,0,0\)/{print $2}'
450x338+25+1240
294x292+13+235
190x403+301+540
246x249+16+738
294x196+16+22
292x196+15+1013
163x267+325+22
248x176+14+540
163x207+321+310
159x200+320+1009
```

[image]

How to put inside or above of each rectangle (in input or output image) the corresponding `WxH+X+Y` text?

For example like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your OS and version of Imagemagick? Syntax will be different on Windows than Linux/Max OSX

Comment: hi, using cygwin (linux emulator) with Imagemagick7. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based upon your comment, what you want to do in Imagemagick is the following with the input on the desktop.  Note that you just need the X and Y offsets from the bbox as the argument to +X+Y in -annotate.

Input:

[image]

```
cd
cd desktop
bboxArr=(`convert images.jpg \
-fuzz 5% -fill none -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" \
-channel rgba -fill white +opaque none -fill black +opaque white \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=5000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 cleaned.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
num=${#bboxArr[*]}
echo $num
convert images.jpg tmp.png
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=${bboxArr[$i]}
echo $bbox
ww=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f1`
hh=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f2`
xo=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f3`
yo=`echo $bbox | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f4`
xo=$((xo+10))
yo=$((yo+10))
convert tmp.png \
-gravity northwest -pointsize 14 -font arial-bold -fill white \
-undercolor black -annotate +${xo}+${yo} "$bbox" tmp.png
done
convert tmp.png images_labeled.jpg
rm -f cleaned.png tmp.png
```

[image]

Comment: It works just perfect! Thanks so much. I only see that it takes seeveral to finish the script in image that has about 50 rectangles. One question, I see you use `-connected-components 8`. Why is better to use 8 than 4?

Comment: rectangular images so 8-connectivty makes sense. But it likely won't matter

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do that in Imagemagick 6.

Create an empty folder (called test) and put the input image inside. Cd to the folder. Then create a nice clean binary image for the connected components. (Note that I used floodfill so as not to change your colors inside the regions.) Then capture the bounding boxes into an array.  The loop over the array and crop and annotate each subsection.

Unix Syntax for Imagemagick 6

```
cd
cd desktop/test
bboxArr=(`convert images.jpg \
-fuzz 5% -fill none -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" \
-channel rgba -fill white +opaque none -fill black +opaque white \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=5000 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 cleaned.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
num=${#bboxArr[*]}
echo $num
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=${bboxArr[$i]}
echo $bbox
convert images.jpg -crop $bbox +repage \
-gravity north -pointsize 14 -font arial-bold -fill white \
-undercolor black -annotate +0+50 "$bbox" images_crop_$i.jpg
done
```

If using Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick.

Comment: Excellent your way to do it. I see I wasn´t clear with the output image I shared. I updated the output image in my original post. I meant to  "annotate" the text for each rectangle inside each one in their position within the input image (not crop each rectangle), then the output would be the input image but with the correspondig text `WxH+x+y` of each rectangle . I hope make sense. Thanks

Comment: @Rasec Malkic. Can you figure that out or do you need help doing it from what I posted?

Comment: I´ve tried changing the convert command inside the for loop from yours to this one `convert input.png -pointsize 14 -font arial-bold -fill white \
-undercolor black -annotate $bbox "$bbox" out_nv.jpg`, but in output image only shows one text in wrong position. What is wrong?